# How to get latest post value if first post is empty in wordpress

Tags: custom-field

I am working on wordpress custom field. I am facing problem to get custom field value if latest post custom field value is empty then display second latest post  or from other post custom field value. My custom field is video if latest post have no video then show 2 latest post video value.I dont know how to get 2latest post custom field value.

Here is my code:-

```
<?php 

                $page_num = $paged;
                if ($pagenum='') $pagenum =1;
              while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
                $args = array(
                    'posts_per_page'      => 1,
                    'paged' => $page_num,
                    'order' => 'DESC',
                    'orderby' => 'post_date',
                    'offset'=> 0,
                    'meta_query'  => array(
                        array(
                            'key' => 'video'
                        )
                    )

                 );
                $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
                $specials = get_post_meta( $post->ID,'video'); 
                foreach( $specials as $special): setup_postdata($special);

                echo '<iframe width="699" height="269" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$special.'?controls=1&showinfo=0&rel=0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';

                     endforeach;
                endwhile; 
                wp_reset_query();
             ?>
```

kindly advice me any solution.

Comment: At first glance, your query should only be returning one post and that post must have a value for key = video. Else, add `'compare' => 'EXISTS'` (assuming you're on > WP3.5) to your meta_query array. Also, check what you have in your `$loop` variable, as I suspect you might need a `true` as third param of [`get_post_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta).

Comment: @Strap1 - Setting the third parameter of `get_post_meta()`, `$single`, to `true` would mean that only one value is returned, not an array of values. With the inclusion of the `foreach` loop I would summise that the OP want's multiple values for the key in question (if they exist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt was not to far away (+1 for trying, and crucially posting what you had tried), all you had to do really was add a compare of `EXISTS` to your meta query.

The `meta_query` parameter can be a bit of a beast to wrap your head around, and just in case you've not found it I'd recommend having a read of the [Class Reference for WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), specifically for [Custom Field Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters).

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => 1,
    'paged'             => (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
    'order'             => 'DESC',
    'orderby'           => 'post_date',
    'meta_query'        => array(
        'relation'      => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'       => 'video',
            'compare'   => 'EXISTS'
        ),
        array(
            'key'       => 'video',
            'value'     => '',
            'compare'   => '!='
        )
    )

);
$loop = new WP_Query($args);

if($loop->have_posts()) : while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();

        $specials = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'video'); 

        foreach($specials as $special): setup_postdata($special);

            echo '<iframe width="699" height="269" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$special.'?controls=1&showinfo=0&rel=0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';

        endforeach;

    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
```

---

**Additional**

As an added redundancy I've also added a check to ensure that the a `video` custom field actually contains a value. While I believe that the WP post edit screen will not actually allow you to save an empty custom value, I can't be sure that you are updating it that way so thought it best to include.

However, if you don't want to include that check you can change the `meta_query` parameter to this -

```
'meta_query'        => array(
    array(
        'key'       => 'video',
        'compare'   => 'EXISTS'
    )
)
```

Comment: You are welcome. And if happy with the anser, please accept it by clicking on the **tick**.